# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (c++) at random places

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow, exc-bad-access

Alright, I'm trying to make a simple flood it game. Something like this: http://floodit.appspot.com Using SFML.

I already have the board in place and as a player it works great. By pressing the letters R,B,P,Y,etc that each correspond to a color, I can change the color of the board, until I get to the win condition. 
What I wanted to add was a small AI that examines the board, solves it in a minimum number of moves, and return that number plus five as the upper limit to the human. This would make the game much more interesting for the player as the board will have a different upper limit every time the game is run.

However, I sometimes it works, and sometimes I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS at random points in the code, almost always stopping at points that are attempting to access specific parts in the board array. But I am sure that these parts exist, so I doubt it's as a result of Deallocation, or pointers being modified. It could be a stack overflow but I'm only recursing about 100 levels deep everytime I get the error. 
The part I get the error is usually somewhere within the these functions:

```
enum col // The colours of the squares
{
    Red,Green,Blue,Purple,Orange,Yellow,AI
};

enum dir // The directions that the function looks in once the player presses a colour
{
    stop,Up,Right,Down,Left
};

void move(int& i,int& j,dir x)
    {
    switch(x)
    {
        case Up:
            i--;
            break;
        case Right:
            j++;
            break;
        case Left:
            j--;
            break;
        case Down:
            i++;
            break;
        default: /*Do Nothing*/;
    }
}


dir get_direction(col board_colors[][size],int i,int j,col current)
{
    //If the coordinates of the surrounding squares are inside the board and greater than zero, check whether they are the same colour as the current square or not

    if((i - 1 > 0) && board_colors[i-1][j] == current)
        return Up;
    else if((j + 1 != size) && board_colors[i][j+1] == current)
        return Right;
    else if((i + 1 != size) && board_colors[i+1][j] == current)
        return Down;
    else if((j - 1 > 0) && board_colors[i][j-1] == current)
        return Left;
    else
        return stop;
}


void reset_temp_board(col temp[size][size])
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            temp[i][j]=AI;
}


int get_land_mass(col temp[size][size])
{
    int mass=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            if(temp[i][j]!=AI)
                mass++;
    return mass;
}

void append_to_temp(col AIBoard[size][size],col temp[size][size],int i,int j,dir x, col current, int color_freq[6])
{
    move(i, j, x);

    temp[i][j]=current;
    AIBoard[i][j]=AI;

    x = get_direction(AIBoard, i, j, current);

    while(x != stop)
    {
        append_to_temp(AIBoard,temp, i, j, x, current,color_freq);
        x = get_direction(AIBoard, i, j, current);
    }
}


void scan_vicinity(col AIBoard[size][size],col mainColor,int i,int j,int color_freq[6])
{
    col temp_board[size][size];

    reset_temp_board(temp_board);

    if(i-1>0 && (AIBoard[i-1][j]!=mainColor) && (AIBoard[i-1][j]!=AI))
    {
        col current=AIBoard[i-1][j];
        append_to_temp(AIBoard, temp_board, i-1, j, stop, current, color_freq);
        color_freq[current]+=get_land_mass(temp_board);
        reset_temp_board(temp_board);
    }

    if(j+1>0 && (AIBoard[i][j+1]!=mainColor) && (AIBoard[i][j+1]!=AI))
    {
        col current=AIBoard[i][j+1];
        append_to_temp(AIBoard, temp_board, i, j+1, stop, current, color_freq);
        color_freq[(int)current]+=get_land_mass(temp_board);
        reset_temp_board(temp_board);
    }

    if(i+1>0 && (AIBoard[i+1][j]!=mainColor) && (AIBoard[i+1][j]!=AI))
    {
        col current=AIBoard[i+1][j];
        append_to_temp(AIBoard, temp_board, i+1, j, stop, current, color_freq);
        color_freq[(int)current]+=get_land_mass(temp_board);
        reset_temp_board(temp_board);
    }

    if(j-1>0 && (AIBoard[i][j-1]!=mainColor) && (AIBoard[i][j-1]!=AI))
    {
        col current=AIBoard[i][j-1];
        append_to_temp(AIBoard, temp_board, i, j-1, stop, current, color_freq);
        color_freq[(int)current]+=get_land_mass(temp_board);
        reset_temp_board(temp_board);
    }


}

void start_analysis(col AIB[size][size], int i, int j, dir x, col current, int color_freq[6])
{
    move(i, j, x); //Moves cursor

    AIB[i][j]=AI;

    scan_vicinity(AIB,current,i,j,color_freq);

    x = get_direction(AIB, i, j, current); //Gets the next direction

    while(x != stop)
    {
        start_analysis(AIB, i, j, x, current,color_freq); //Next turn

        x = get_direction(AIB, i, j, current); //Next direction to check
    }
}

col analyse_board(col AI[size][size]) //returns best choice of color
{
    int color_freq[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    start_analysis(AI, 0, 0, stop, AI[0][0],color_freq);
    return (col)maxIndex(color_freq);
}
```

The Way the AI works is that it moves through the region that is currently under my control, it scans extremes of each block (UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT) and determines whether they are attached to other blocks of different colours. Beginning at the different coloured block it starts running through the small blocks and copying down their locations in a temp board that is used to determine the number of blocks associated with that starting block. Hence it determines the total number of blocks of any specific colour, attached to the extremes of the region that is under my control. 
It then finds the index in the color_freq array (which so happens to be the actual color) that has the maximum number of blocks gained.

Occasionally the code stops at random points in the flood_it function as well
Here's the function:

```
void set_color(col board_colors[][size],RectangleShape board[][size],int i,int j,col New)
{
    Color PURPLE(128,0,128);
    Color ORANGE(255,165,0);
    board_colors[i][j]= New;
    switch(New) //Sets the colour of the rest of the squares to be the same as the new one
    {
        case Red:
            board[i][j].setFillColor(Color::Red);
            break;
        case Green:
            board[i][j].setFillColor(Color::Green);
            break;
        case Blue:
            board[i][j].setFillColor(Color::Blue);
            break;
        case Purple:
            board[i][j].setFillColor(PURPLE);
            break;
        case Orange:
            board[i][j].setFillColor(ORANGE);
            break;
        case Yellow:
            board[i][j].setFillColor(Color::Yellow);
            break;
        default:;
    }
}

dir get_direction(col board_colors[][size],int i,int j,col current)
{
    //If the coordinates of the surrounding squares are inside the board and greater than zero, check whether they are the same colour as the current square or not

    if((i - 1 > 0) && board_colors[i-1][j] == current)
        return Up;
    else if((j + 1 != size) && board_colors[i][j+1] == current)
        return Right;
    else if((i + 1 != size) && board_colors[i+1][j] == current)
        return Down;
    else if((j - 1 > 0) && board_colors[i][j-1] == current)
        return Left;
    else
        return stop;
}

void move(int& i,int& j,dir x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case Up:
            i--;
            break;
        case Right:
            j++;
            break;
        case Left:
            j--;
            break;
        case Down:
            i++;
            break;
        default: /*Do Nothing*/;
    }
}

void start_traversing(RectangleShape board[size][size], col board_colors[][size], int i, int j, dir x, col current,col New)
{
    move(i, j, x); //Moves cursor

    set_color(board_colors, board, i, j, New); //Sets the colour

    x = get_direction(board_colors, i, j, current); //Gets the next direction

    while(x != stop)
    {
        start_traversing(board, board_colors, i, j, x, current, New); //Next turn

        x = get_direction(board_colors, i, j, current); //Next direction to check
    }
}
void flood_it(col board_colors[size][size],RectangleShape board[size][size], col New)
{
    if(WinCondition(board_colors) == 1) //Still more moves left
        start_traversing(board, board_colors,0,0,stop,board_colors[0][0], New);
}
```

So In conclusion, I'm stumped....

Comment: It's probably not as random as you think it is. Have you tried to run in a debugger? Does the crash always happen at different locations? When the crash happens, what are the values of all involved variables? Do the values of all involved variables look okay? Are indexes within limits? You don't write beyond the limits of any array and overwrite the stack?

Comment: `if (j+1>0` doesn't look right for an upper bound...

Comment: solution : never use recursion. Nowhere. Under no circumstance. Recursion is bad in almost every conceivable way - and it doesnt help much if you want to learn a language. Consider exchanging every recursion for an iterative solution and you will have _much_ less problems, its that easy. Just because a method is "cool" it doesnt have to be usable or even production-ready, quite a few errors are traced back to the usage of recursion in productive software ... almost all people here on SO will tell you otherwise - dont mind me, im just the voice of truth in a mere ocean of dreams :-)

Answer (score 0):

Moldinbo is correct!!!!!! , since i'm new to stack exchange i have no idea how to select his answer as the best.

Either way thank you.

I had to use recursion here because i need to retain previous locations of i and j while traversing the board.